# How to properly test Django UpdateView?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views

I have the following unit test

```
def test_category_update_view(self):
    """
    Make sure that a category can be updated
    :return: 
    """
    self.log_user_1_in()

    self.assertEqual('Bacon', self.category.name)

    res = self.client.put(
        reverse(
            'calendars:categories:edit_category',
            kwargs={'calendar_pk': self.calendar.id, 'pk': self.category.id}
        ),
        urlencode({'name': 'bacon is yummy'})
    )

    self.assertEqual('bacon is yummy', self.category.name)

    self.assertEqual(302, res.status_code)
    self.assertEqual(
        reverse('calendars:categories:category_list', kwargs={'calendar_pk': self.calendar.id}),
        res.url
    )
```

[image]

As you can see it's saying that the form is invalid, so my question is why is it invalid? Shouldn't the test client be using the data I gave it? My POST request done in the same fashion is working just fine and passing the proper data.

I haven't posted in a while so forgive me if this is kind of vague. If you need more information to help me please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When you are posting data with `self.client.put/post/patch...` etc you shouldn't urlencode the data you want to send. Your dictionary `{'name': 'bacon is yummy'}` ends up being converted into `'name=bacon+is+yummy'` and Django then can't decode what fields you are sending (if you wanted to send it as `GET` parameters it would make sense though).

Instead, try using this code *without* `urlencode`:

```py
res = self.client.put(
    reverse(
        'calendars:categories:edit_category',
        kwargs={'calendar_pk': self.calendar.id, 'pk': self.category.id}
    ),
    {'name': 'bacon is yummy'}
)
```

[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/)